# Best way to pass large amounts of data from route to view in Node using render?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, rendering

I have a routing file. When a user goes to site.com/page, my route makes a call to an SQL DB and then parses the results and returns them as JSON. Then I use

`res.render('route/to/view', {data: result, moredata: resultTwo})`

which sends data to the view. The problem is that my data is relatively large and takes forever to send to the view. I am 100% sure this is what is making my page run slowly. When I cut the dataset in half, the it displays much quicker. I am also aware that the actual showing of this data is also a factor, but I am strictly concerned with the speed at which it is passed from the routing to the view.

Is it any more efficient to pass a bunch of small chunks rather than one large chunk? Is the only way around this to do gradual passing of small chunks?

Comment: Can't you load first some small amount of data and them, using async request (ajax), load the rest of them?

Answer (score 1):

Passing the data to the view isn't very slow -- what's likely happening is that the template engine is just taking a while to render the data you've provided. The data itself never leaves memory, so there's no 'copy' operation going on.

The best way to speed stuff like this up is to use something like AJAX or websockets.

Here's a typical flow:

- Make a DB request to grab a small number of the total items (let's say 10).
- Pass those to your view and render it immediately to the user.
- Have some AJAX code running in the view that then sends a GET request to your server asynchronously, requesting the rest of the items.
- You can then update the DOM with the newly added data.

This is usually the best way to handle the display of large amounts of data, as the user perceives things to be really quick, even when they're quite slow -- the page loads fast, data is shown quickly, etc.

Comment: Well what makes me think it is the passing that is slow is that I have a console log right before I call the render. Then in the HTML (I am using Angular) I have an init function that gets passed one of the results of the render. When this init gets called, I have another console log. A majority of the time is spent in between these two console logs.

Comment: Ah, if you're using Angular that might be a bit different, as you have to download the data to the Client anyhow -- which is going to take a bit. In general, however, returning a small amount of data and asynchronously fetching the rest should still speed this process up considerably.

Comment: Although, I am using swig to make the data received into JSON before I init. You think that is it? for example, my init looks like `ng-init="init( {{data|json}} )"`

Comment: Yah -- I would guess that would be causing the delay if anything.

Comment: Any idea how I can get around this? I am trying to find a way to pass in the data straight to angular but am getting parsing errors and such.

Comment: I can't think of one :( I'm not an angular expert, however, you might have better luck asking a separate, angular-specific question about that.